# BroadcastReceiver is never called using GCM service

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to implement the new service of GCM for push notifications.
I've seen some similiar posts about that issue and most of them are pointing to the Manifest that missing something. 
Couldn't find what I'm missing there:

**Manifest.xml** (Original with all permisions etc.. in case that's efecting something)

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.catchme2"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="12"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <permission android:name="com.example.catchme2.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.catchme2.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />


    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock"
        android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.catchme2.FbActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
          <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
          <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="MyAPIKEY"/>
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/app_id"/>
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name="MainActivity"></activity>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.example.catchme2.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.GCM_RECEIVED_ACTION" />
                <category android:name="com.example.catchme2" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name="com.example.catchme2.GcmIntentService" 
            android:enabled="true"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**BroadcastReceiver.class**

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                GcmIntentService.class.getName());
        // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }

}
```

**IntentService.class**

```
public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {

    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
    static final String TAG = "GCMDemo";

    public GcmIntentService(String name) {
        super("GcmIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
        // The getMessageType() intent parameter must be the intent you received
        // in your BroadcastReceiver.
        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

        if (!extras.isEmpty()) {  // has effect of unparcelling Bundle
            /*
             * Filter messages based on message type. Since it is likely that GCM
             * will be extended in the future with new message types, just ignore
             * any message types you're not interested in, or that you don't
             * recognize.
             */
            if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                    MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                    MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: " +
                        extras.toString());
            // If it's a regular GCM message, do some work.
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                    MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {
                // This loop represents the service doing some work.
                for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Working... " + (i+1)
                            + "/5 @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                }
                Log.i(TAG, "Completed work @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                // Post notification of received message.
                sendNotification("Received: " + extras.toString());
                Log.i(TAG, "Received: " + extras.toString());
            }
        }
        // Release the wake lock provided by the WakefulBroadcastReceiver.
        GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);

    }

    private void sendNotification(String msg) {
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(this, FbActivity.class), 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setContentTitle("GCM Notification")
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
        .bigText(msg))
        .setContentText(msg);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

I'm using this line to send the massege:

```
gcm.send(SENDER_ID + "@gcm.googleapis.com", id, data);
```

The sender_id is my project number at google api console, and the id is always the same (1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gcm.send` is for sending GCM messages from your application to your server (via GCM Cloud Connection Server). Your manifest looks fine, but in order for `gcm.send` to do anything, you must have a server connected to GCM Cloud Connection Server. And since you are trying to send a message to the server, you won't see anything in your device (even if the message was sent successfully to your server) and BroadcastReceiver won't be called (unless your server sends a message back to the device).

Comment: Hah what was I thinking, it couldnt be that easy! Thanks for the point, seems that I have work to do, Thanks!